# I'm trying to create a quiz with JavaScript and I can't get my button to work

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get my head around JavaScript at all, I'm trying to create a quiz but every way I go about it, I can't seem to get the form to submit. This is just the section of the code from my HTML website.

```
<b>Quiz</b>
<br><br>
    <center><p>Q 1) What colour is this laptop?</p>
        <table width="200">
            <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="radio" id="a1" value="a1" />
                Orange</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="radio" id="a2" value="a1" />
                White</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="radio" id="a3" value="a1" />
                Blue</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="radio" id="a4" value="a1" />
                Red</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"
            onClick="fSubmit()" /></center>
        </p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function fSubmit(){
                    var correctanswer = document.getElementById("a3")
                        if (correctanswer.checked *** true) {
                            alert("Correct!")
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Incorrect!")
                        }
                    }   
            </script>
```

Comment: What is `if (correctanswer.checked *** true)` supposed to be?

Comment: Is there a `<form>` tag around this? If not, there's nothing to submit.

Comment: @barmar No need for a form since he is using `onclick`, not `onsubmit`.

Comment: @FedericoMP But he said that the problem is that the form isn't submitting. His Javascript doesn't submit the form, it just does an alert, so I thought he wanted it to submit after the JS runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <b>Quiz</b>
    <br><br>
    <form>
    <center>
        <p>Q 1) What colour is this laptop?</p>
        <table width="200">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="a1" value="a1" />
                    Orange
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="a2" value="a1" />
                    White
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="a3" value="a1" />
                    Blue
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="a4" value="a1" />
                    Red
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"
                   onclick="fSubmit()" />
    </center>
    </form>
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fSubmit() {
                    var correctanswer = document.getElementById("a3")
                        if (correctanswer.checked === true) {
                            alert("Correct!")
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Incorrect!")
                        }
                    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Add the form tag. It will work in some browsers without form tag. It is a good practice to place a form tag. Also in if, replace *** with ===

Comment: this one has fixed it for me thanks, how can i go about having multiple questions with one submit button that gives a score?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a JavaScript error (such as the *** instead of === in your code example), the click event will not fire. You can open up the JavaScript debugger (sometimes called console) in your browser to see any errors.

Also, it seems as though you do not want to "submit" your button click to the server, so the input type should be button (not submit) or else use the on submit event on the form instead of the onclick event on the button.